# Delete text bottom line in <a> link with just an image

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have a list of icons in which each one is a link to a phone, facebook link, twitter...

It was working fine in a table, but now I want to delete the table to keep just the buttons and set 3 white spaces between each one.

This is my table right now:

```
<table width:100% border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td  id="table_column_phone" style="display:;text-align:center">
            <a id="phone_to_link" href='' rel='external'>
              <img id="image_phone" src="./images/phone_64.png" width="35px"/>
            </a>

          </td>
          <td id="table_column_mail" style="display:;text-align:center">
            <a id="mail_to_link" href="">
              <img id="image_mail" src="./images/mail_64.png" width="35px"/>
            </a>

          </td>
          <td id="table_column_web" style="display:;text-align:center">
            <a href="" id="web_to_link">
              <img id="image_web" src="./images/web_64.png" width="35px"/>
            </a>

          </td>
          <td  id="table_column_facebook" style="display:;text-align:center">
            <a id="facebook_to_link" href="">
              <img id="image_facebook" src="./images/facebook_64.png" width="35px"/>
            </a>

          </td>
          <td id="table_column_twitter" style="display:;text-align:center">
            <a href="" id="twitter_to_link">
              <img id="image_twitter" src="./images/twitter_64.png" width="35px"/>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

And it is shown, just with 3 icons (I hide some of them if there is no data) (This represent and image_> []):

```
[]        []       []
```

If I quit width:100% in table or quit table at all (td and tr also) and just put  and icons with some white spaces ($nbsp;) I got something like this:

```
[]_   []_   []
```

I don't know why I am getting "_" after icon. With the exactly same code.

Any idea? Do you need to see something more of my code? I will post it.

For example:

```
 <a id="phone_to_link" href='' rel='external'>
              <img id="image_phone" src="./images/phone_64.png" width="35px"/>
            </a>

            <a id="mail_to_link" href="">
              <img id="image_mail" src="./images/mail_64.png" width="35px"/>
            </a>
            <a href="" id="web_to_link">
              <img id="image_web" src="./images/web_64.png" width="35px"/>
            </a>
            <a id="facebook_to_link" href="">
              <img id="image_facebook" src="./images/facebook_64.png" width="35px"/>
            </a>
            <a href="" id="twitter_to_link">
              <img id="image_twitter" src="./images/twitter_64.png" width="35px"/>
            </a>
```

shows:

```
[]_[]_[]_[]_[]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a class name to the links

```
<a href=... class="button">...</a>
```

and use CSS

```
a.button {
text-decoration: none;
}
```